# Двигающиеся платформы

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Я сделал двигающиеся платформы, по этому видео.

[Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMZnSZswTmU&index=23&list=PLiyfvmtjWC_Up8XNvM3OSqgbJoMQgHkVz)

Но есть проблема, когда мой персонаж становится на платформу, то он начинает судорожно вибрировать.

**Скрипт MovingPlatform:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MovingPlatform : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject platform;

    public float moveSpeed;

    public Transform currentPoint;

    public Transform[] points;

    public int pointSelection;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        currentPoint=points[pointSelection];

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        platform.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (platform.transform.position, currentPoint.position, Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);

        if (platform.transform.position == currentPoint.position) 
        {
            pointSelection++;

            if(pointSelection == points.Length)
            {
                pointSelection=0;
            }

            currentPoint = points[pointSelection];
        }

    }
}
```

**Скрипт PlayerController:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioSource jumpSoundEffect;

    [Header ("Движение")]
    public float JumpHeight;
    public float moveSpeed;
    private bool doubleJumped;
    private float moveVelocity;


    [Header ("Земля")]
    [Space(10)]
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    private bool grounded;

    [Header ("Отбрасывание")]
    [Space(10)]
    public float knockback;
    public float knockbackLength;
    public float knockbackCount;
    public bool  knockbackFromRight;

    private Animator anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (groundCheck.position,groundCheckRadius,whatIsGround);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if(Time.timeScale == 0f)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (grounded) 
        {
            doubleJumped=false;
        }

        anim.SetBool ("Grounded", grounded);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && grounded) 
        {
            //GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, JumpHeight);
            Jump ();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && !doubleJumped && !grounded) 
        {
            //GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, JumpHeight);
            Jump ();
            doubleJumped=true;
        }

        moveVelocity = 0f;

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) 
        {
            //GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (moveSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
            moveVelocity = moveSpeed;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A))
        {
            //GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (-moveSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
            moveVelocity = -moveSpeed;
        }

        if (knockbackCount <= 0) {

            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (moveVelocity, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.y);

        } else {

            if(knockbackFromRight)
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (-knockback, knockback);

            if(!knockbackFromRight)
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (knockback, knockback);

            knockbackCount -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        var speed = Mathf.Abs(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x);
        anim.SetFloat ("Speed", speed);

        if(speed > 0.1f)
        {
            //Баг блоха.
            if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x > 0)
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(4f,4f,4f);
            else if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x < 0)
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(-4f,4f,4f);
        }

    }


    public void Jump()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, JumpHeight);
        jumpSoundEffect.Play ();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.transform.tag == "MovingPlatform") 
        {
            transform.parent = other.transform;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.transform.tag == "MovingPlatform") 
        {
            transform.parent = null;
        }
    }
}
```

И скрипт камеры, которая ходит за персонажем:

```
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {

    private Vector2 velocity;

    public float smoothTimeY;
    public float smoothTimeX;

    //public GameObject player;
    public PlayerController player;

    public bool bounds;

    public Vector3 minCameraPos;
    public Vector3 maxCameraPos;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        //player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Player");
        player = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {

        float posX = Mathf.SmoothDamp (transform.position.x, player.transform.position.x, ref velocity.x, smoothTimeX);
        float posY = Mathf.SmoothDamp (transform.position.y, player.transform.position.y, ref velocity.x, smoothTimeY);

        transform.position = new Vector3 (posX, posY, transform.position.z);

        if (bounds)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, minCameraPos.x, maxCameraPos.x),
                                             Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, minCameraPos.y, maxCameraPos.y),
                                             Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.z, minCameraPos.z, maxCameraPos.z));
        }
    }
}
```

Что я мог пропустить?

[Мой проект](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kn5mzpn0ccn4yn/Lost%20Penguin%20v.0.0.14.5.rar?dl=0)

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Надо было еще скрипт камеры, ходящей за персонажем кинуть))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша проблема заключается не в персонаже как таковом, и не в платформе, а в том, что вы управляете позицией камеры  в `FixedUpdate`, который в большей степени нужен для объектов с компонентом `Rigidbody/Rigidbody2D`. А вам нужен метод `LateUpdate` .

`LateUpdate` - как раз таки, [ссылаясь на документацию](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html)

> This is useful to order script execution. For example a follow camera
>   should always be implemented in LateUpdate because it tracks objects
>   that might have moved inside Update.

желательно и нужно использовать для камеры и её движения.

Это основная проблема. И поместив перемещение камеры в тот метод, в принципе, должно все разрешиться. НО (!)...

Также попробуйте на всякий случай вынести расчет `posX` и `posY` в метод `Update`. Чтоб расчет был там, а в `LateUpdate` уже просто писать

```
transform.position = new Vector3 (posX, posY, transform.position.z);
```

так как `LateUpdate` вызывается после всех функций Update. Поэтому, собственно, движение камеры там и располагают.

А также посмотрите настройки `smoothTimeX`, `smoothTimeY`, которые тоже в итоге заставляют вашу камеру дрожать при определенных значениях

Comment: Изменил название метод FixedUpdate на LateUpdate, теперь пингвина трясёт везде,не только на платформе.+ Вынес posX и posY в Update, но transform.position = new Vector3 (posX, posY, transform.position.z); их не видит.

p.s. на будущее, не стоит брать код с разных видео =D

Comment: @ArtikSlayer во-первых где вы изменили `FixedUpdate`  надеюсь в `FollowCamera.cs`, а не у персонажа? Трясется у вас везде из-за `smoothTimeX/smoothTimeY`, как я описал в ответе..Поставьте нули и убедитесь.Что-то там надо менять........`Вынес posX и posY в Update, но transform.position = new Vector3 (posX, posY, transform.position.z); их не видит.` - правильно... их надо в переменные класса вынести. а так они у вас локальные для метода...логично...надеюсь вас не надо азам учить?))........`p.s. на будущее, не стоит брать код с разных видео` - это вы наверное себе? А то код взят у вас из проекта

Comment: В общем на данный момент помогло 2 вещи. Сменить FixedUpdate на LateUpdate и заменить moothTimeX и smoothTimeY на 0 либо 0.001, но 0.01 не подходит. Спасибо, не думал, что проблема может заключаться в камере =D